# unable to update properties of aspect using alfresco-opencmis-extension

Tags: alfresco, cmis, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I have an aspect with name "**alfrescoDocs:uploadedfrom**" and it has single property with name "**alfrescoDocs:uploadSource**". I am using alfresco-opencmis-extension to attached this aspect with document on creation and set some value in its property. I am using code below.

```
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, "test12");
    properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:document,P:cm:titled,P:alfrescoDocs:uploadedfrom");
    properties.put("cmis:description", "AliNawab");
    properties.put("alfrescoDocs:uploadSource", "SugarCRM");

    Document doc = session.getRootFolder().createDocument(properties, null, null);
```

This code successfully attaches the aspect with newly created document. But the value of property **"alfrescoDocs:uploadSource"** is not updating.

I am using: **http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom** url for connection.

Also I need to do exactly the same in php.

Comment: yes I have solved this issue following this forum : https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-api/setting-aspect-property-using-cmis-06122014-1046

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I used http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom.

seems 
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom has some changes around aspect props.